# add a dynamic variable data into include function in php

Tags: php

I am trying to add a dynamic variable into include function in php
Here is the code I am trying to do but didn't work

```
$theme = "1";

include("s-include/themes/starecom-theme".$theme."/index.php");
```

$theme data is 1/2/3

and I want to include folder no 1/2/3 into include

its didn't give any error only blank page view. 
actual url : s-include/themes/starecom-theme1/index.php but theme1/2/3 changed dynamically from the database which selected

Please help me to solved this issue

Thanks to All

Comment: if you can share the error log then we can help you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'didnt work'? Share error. For start, we can say that directory doesnt exists.

Comment: its didn't give any error only blank actual url : s-include/themes/starecom-theme1/index.php but theme1/2/3 changed dynamically from the database which selected

Comment: Folder 1/2/3 are separate folders or its like starecom-theme1, starecom-theme2.. if folders are separate then you have to add / after starecom-theme in include path..

Comment: no full folder is starecom-theme1, starecom-theme2

Comment: So you have to include `starecom-theme1` , `starecom-theme2`, `starecom-theme3` if you get value `1/2/3` from db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `1/2/3` from data-base and you have to include each file (seperated with `/`) then try below code. It will explode your data then include each file.

```
$theme  = "1/2/3";
$theme_array = explode("/", $theme);
foreach ($theme_array as $key => $value) {
  include("s-include/themes/starecom-theme".$value."/index.php");
}
```